# What is the best way to query posts based on live data?

Tags: query, post-meta, meta-query

I work on developing plugin for WordPress. 
In each post, there are rating bar that users can rate 1-5 star to post.
I calculate the **grow rate** based on **(Stars in past 7 day from now)**.
I want to show posts sorted by **grow rate**.
What is the best way to **saving grow rate and then query posts based on it**?
One way is that save grow rate in post meta and update post meta in every time that users rate, but if a post doesn't have any rate for long time, its grow rate still out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

you must implement logic for edge cases, you could get the posts and check when was the last time their rate meta was updated! depending on that you decide if you can display or not the post on your search result